# How can I send mail in office 365 REST API V2.0 in a service without giving "Send Mail as any user" permission?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've created an Azure AD application and I want to send emails on behalf of some users(limited list) in a daemon service. I use Azure AD v2.0 endpoint to authenticate to the Microsoft Office 365. When I give "Send mail as any user" permission to the app and use "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users/{user}/sendmail", It works fine. Is there any way to send mail as a user without giving this permission and user interaction? This permission is too wide. How can I limit it to some users?
Thanks

Comment: All the permissions here, you could refer to it : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#mail-permissions

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on the ball, but there seems to be an answer for this now. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) are some docs limiting access to certain groups.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suppose you have two questions.

First question, you want to send mail as a user without user interaction.

Second question, you want to limit the sender of mail to some users, instead of all user.

For your question #1, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). As the description of the content, we can get access without a user.

Based on my test, we can try the following steps:

Step 1, we should get administrator consent:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                                           {
                                               ClientId = clientId,
                                               Authority = authority,
                                               RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               Scope = "openid profile",
                                               ResponseType = "id_token",
                                               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, NameClaimType = "name" },
                                               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                                               {
                                                                   AuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                                                                   SecurityTokenValidated = this.OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                                                               }
                                           });

ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId), Startup.redirectUri,
                                                                                       new ClientCredential(Startup.clientSecret), null, appTokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance());
AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { MSGraphScope });
```

We can refer to [the simple code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2).

Step 2, we can use the Graph API to send email.

For your question #2, we can set some email addresses to send emails, such as 'simple-send-mail@outlook.com'. Then we can user API: `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail`
like this:
`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/simple-send-mail@outlook.com/sendMail`. For more detail, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail).